Film that takes place in Middle Ages
The movie is set in medieval England? Scotland? Ireland? It's about a girl, and she was promised to marry a guy from another powerful rich family. She's always in the forest, even when she was a child, and that's where she met a wandering poor blonde farmer boy. The boy had been spying on her for a while before she noticed him. I think they become best friends, not sure, and if they did, they grow up together and end up falling in love. The girl does not want to marry the guy she was promised to, and he is an evil man. She's alone in the forest when he attempts to rape her and I think she ends up killing him. I don't remember much else. The movie is in English and was most likely filmed in the 2000s. 

This sounds a bit stereotypical; there must be a lot of different stories that fit this basic profile. Can you remember any more details? You might also want to provide a more descriptive title.

It sounds like the TV Movie "Tess of the D'Urbervilles (1998)"
and "Tess of the D'Urbervilles 2008"  (TV Mini-Series)

Young country girl Tess Durbyfield goes to work for her aristocratic
  relatives, the D'Urbervilles, in an attempt at helping her family to
  raise some money. Her cousin Alec falls in love with her and
  seduces/rapes her.

